# Firebase & Ionic hybrid App

Tags: mobile, ionic-framework, firebase, development-environment

I am new to app Development,
 
I am busy with a App with firebase as backend and using ionic framework to build the app. 
Following are my questions,
Do I need hosting for my app ?
In my App I have to send some emails to number of users on certain action, shall I trigger it direct from App or have a service built and trigger this service all the time ?
As I am new, any guidance is welcome.

Comment: 1. Yes, if you want to show it on play store then purchase service from google .Cost would be $25 and for ios it is $99. For firebase check https://firebase.google.com/pricing/                        2. For email make a mail service and do ajax call from your app. It will work,

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your application requirements as you are using `firebase` you can use `free plan`. if you want to scale then you can purchase.
For sending emails it should be better that you make an `emailSending` service that take complete parameters of `message body` for sending message and call that service on that particular activity or action

Comment: If I can do my app build on localhost, and can create APK to put on App store, then do I still need to host my app on firebase or anywhere else ?